# Bootstrap modal not hiding (ASP.NE MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal with some inputs and button.

Here is code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Добавить получателя</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
            <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email2" ,="" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" ,="" placeholder="Ф.И.О">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone2" ,="" placeholder="Телефон">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profession2" ,="" placeholder="Ваша профессия">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Comment2" ,="" placeholder="Комментарий">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="button" id="send_mail2" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 40px;">
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When I click button, script send AJAX request and on back end method send email to recipient.

Here is JS script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send_mail2').click(function () {
        send_email2();
    });
});
function send_email2() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            From2: $('#email2').val(),
            Name2: $('#name2').val(),
            Telephone2: $('#telephone2').val(),
            Profession2: $('#profession2').val(),
            Comment2: $('#Comment2').val(),
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("SendEmail2", "Home")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                alert("Sucess");
                //$("#myModalDoctors").modal();
                 $("#myModal2").modal("hide");
            } else {

                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

With back-end all okay and alert is working. But modal is not hiding . Where can be trouble?

I tried also `$("#myModal2").modal('hide');` and it not works too.

Comment: why are u including jquery.js and jqueryui js file in modal template ?

Comment: How are you showing it?  Are you showing it via `modal('show')`?

Comment: do you get any error in console ?

Comment: `<button class="bolshe-button" style="margin-top:45px; width: 300px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Записаться на курс</button>`

Like this @BrianMains

Comment: Nope. any erros@Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code and it's working. Probably your ajax call is not firing success callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen backgrounds with centered content">
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Добавить получателя</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email2" ,="" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" ,="" placeholder="Ф.И.О">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone2" ,="" placeholder="Телефон">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profession2" ,="" placeholder="Ваша профессия">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Comment2" ,="" placeholder="Комментарий">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
                            <input type="button" id="send_mail2" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 40px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#send_mail2').click(function() {
            $("#myModal2").modal("hide");
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try the above code? It's working(i mean it's closing the modal) when click on send_email button

Comment: Will try now it

Comment: Let me know if it works. And please don't forget to marked it as correct one.

Comment: Error, was in script order in View

Comment: Yes, i thought about that earlier. It's not good practice to add scripts inside modal or any div. scripts should be added either in header or bottom of the page.